# Variable/List Component scope in R?

Tags: r, function, scope, global-variables, lexical-scope

I come from OOP background (C#/Java to be specific) and I really do not understand how R treat the variable from outside the function.

I made this example:

```
result = list();
result$total = 0;
result$count = 0;

result$something = "abc";

a = 1:10;
b = 10:20;

mapply(function(x, y) {
    print(result$something);

    # Does not work with either = or <--
    result$total <-- result$total + x + y;
    result$count <-- result$count + 1;

    print(result$count);
}, x = a, y = b);

result$average = result$total / result$count;
print(result$total);
print(result$count);
print(result$average);
```

Here, clearly `result` is available to the anonymous function because the program did print "abc" 10 times.

However, the change to its component `total` and `count` does not survive. 10 times it prints 1 for the `result$count`, and the final 3 lines are 0, 0 and NaN.

Why is this happening? What should I do in this case, if I want the function to be able to change the variable value?

Note: in my real case, `result` is NOT a global variable, but is inside another function, and I will use `return (result)` from the function.

Comment: Did you mean to use `<<-` and not `<--`? The later is normal assignment followed by numerical unary negation

Comment: Within the function you can use `<<-` to change/ create the variable in the parent environment. But this would not change it within the function itself! So if you stil want to print `count`then you need `result$count <<- result$count + 1` and `result$count <- result$count + 1`.

For a better understanding of the usage of environments and what is called when you could read this: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html

Comment: I'll add the obligatory comment that R is not meant to be used this way (functions modifying external objects). If you need to modify an object in a function, you should generally pass that object as an argument, modify it and then return and reassign it. Don't delve into things like `<<-` and `assign` while you're still learning R, they will become a crutch that cause you to write code in patterns from other languages rather than learning R.

Comment: Thank you, I was my mistake using `<--` instead of `<<-`. `<<-` works correctly, but as @joran mentioned, what should I do instead? How can I pass a single variable into `mapply` anonymous function?

Comment: mapply isn’t what you want here. Just write a for loop if you can’t vectorize it.